# LibGDX (Freetype) font ugly and unreadably

Tags: fonts, libgdx, scale, font-size, freetype

I'm using a Freetype font to display text. But the font always looks:
 #1 **Unreadable**(throught decreasing the font size):
[image: Unreadable]

```
        generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/LDFComicSans.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = 5;
        font = generator.generateFont(parameter); // font size 12 pixels
        font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
        generator.dispose();
```

or #2 **Ugly**(through scaling):
[image: Ugky]

```
generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/LDFComicSans.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 30;
font = generator.generateFont(parameter); // font size 12 pixels
font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
font.getData().setScale(0.15F, 0.15F);
font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
generator.dispose();
```

These are the camera/viewport settings I use:

```
  camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        viewport = new StretchViewport(100,100,camera);
        viewport.apply();
```

I think it's because the viewport is too small but I really don't want to change it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I had a similar problem like on image 2. I was trying to draw the text on a float y position (like y=26.14) and the letters were unaligned. Try to draw it always on rounded y (25,26,27)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following your #2 version, call `setUseIntegerPositions(false)` on the font. By default it rounds character positions to the nearest integer, which looks terrible with a tiny viewport. You may want to give it mip maps and use MipMapLinearLinear for the min filter to compensate for the characters not being aligned with screen pixels (to reduce blurriness).

Comment: It should be noted that this is just as valuable when creating a BitmapFont from a .fnt file.